# Automatically mirror git repository

Tags: git, mirroring

I'm have got a git I access via ssh. I'd like to backup the server in another to location by mirroring. I've got another server where I can setup another git repository.

My idea is: Forward in some way the commit from server 1 to server 2 automatically, is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by: “Forward automatically”?

Comment: I mean: the server A sends changes to server B automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To automatically carry out actions after a push was performed on a repository the [`post-receive`](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) hook can be used. It will be called once the entire pushing process is finished.

You can push to the other server by simply using a standard `git push` with the `--mirror` [1] option in there:

```
#!/bin/bash
git push --mirror git@example.com:mirror.git
```

[1]

> ```
>    --mirror
>        Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under
>        refs/ (which includes but is not limited to refs/heads/,
>        refs/remotes/, and refs/tags/) be mirrored to the remote
>        repository. Newly created local refs will be pushed to the remote
>        end, locally updated refs will be force updated on the remote end,
>        and deleted refs will be removed from the remote end. This is the
>        default if the configuration option remote.<remote>.mirror is set.
> ```

Comment: Is there a way to use the ssh password?

Comment: @greywolf82 I recommend using SSH keys for this purpose. You can read about them in GitHub help: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ Generate an SSH key on your server A and add it to the proper account of server B.

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
git clone
```

if you have you a client client installed on the backup server. This can then be set to run on a regular basis for automatic updates.